# Implementing generic types to a language

Tags: oop, generics, types, instantiation

I want to add support for generics to a language, but before I do I need to understand more clearly what generics are inside.

My current understanding is that instantiating the class:

```
class ArrayList<T>
{
    public int add(T object)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Creates an instance where the argument type of `T` on `add` must be the same as the type argument on `new ArrayList<T>()` where `T` is a real type.

Implementing this seems pretty simple, but only for this use-case.  It becomes a more complicated concept when it needs to support introspection.  For example, I **wouldn't** say that:

```
true === (new ArrayList<Date>() instanceof ArrayList)
```

but I would say that:

```
true === (new ArrayList<Date>() instanceof ArrayList<Date>)
```

My question is, when using `ArrayList<Date>` as a type reference, is it a type derived of `ArrayList<T>`, or is it a class in its own right, for example is:

```
$list = new ArrayList<Date>();
```

an instance of:

```
class ArrayList
{
    public int add(Date $object)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or is it an instance of `ArrayList<T>` where `T` is `Date`?

Comment: `ArrayList<T>` is only used in class declaration if this is what you mean. using `ArrayList<T>` as type makes no sense (if `T` is not known).

Comment: @Hacketo I know, I'm talking in a more abstract sense.  I'm trying to figure out if the instantiated object still holds information that it is an instance of a generic type, or if a new kind of virtual class is created with the type parameters expanded which is the object is now an instance of.  This question is quite important for me because it will decide on where the type parameters propagate from throughout the language.  If they propagate from instantiation, then the types need only be referenced, if  from the class name, the class needs to be copied (figuratively) from the declaration.

Comment: My comment was about the statement `new ArrayList<Date>() instanceof ArrayList<T>` that cant be true when T is not known, if `T` is `Date`, then you have the same result than `new ArrayList<Date>() instanceof ArrayList<Date>`. `T`` is only used for generics classes declaration like a variable that hold a type.

Comment: @Hacketo Oh I see, I'll remove the `<T>` then, it will have the same meaning in the question.  Essentially what that was implying was that a `ArrayList<Date>` shoudn't equal `ArrayList` because `ArrayList` as a class without parameterized types wouldn't exist.

Comment: My guess would be that if `ArrayList<T>` still exists at runtime (reflection, w/e) you need to use the second choice, because that would mean that you would have to create these classes at runtime if they do not exists (with the first choice). so `$list` is an instance of `ArrayList<T>` where `T` is `Date`

Comment: @Hacketo That does sound like a good case.  They would still need to be chained back to the declaration some how.

Comment: Java uses [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), thus `$list` is an instance of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java generics and C++ templates looks similar at first sight but are implemented in an opposite way. As said in comment by Steffen Kreutz, java uses type erasure for its generics. Type erasure means that at compile time, java controls access to a generic class, but at run time, all type information is gone, and `ArrayList<Date>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` share **exactly** the same code.

This would be quite different with templates. In templates, each concrete class is implemented at compile time, so (in C++)  `vector<double>` and `vector<char>` are two different classes, and their compiled code will be different because one will take double parameters, when the other will take chars and they are not passed the same way in the stack.

If you need a generic class to know the type it can accept, you have to explictely use an attribute to keep it. For example:

```
class MyGen<T> {
    class<T> myClazz;

    MyGen(class<T> clazz) {
        myClass = clazz;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can then use reflection on myClazz because it is a true class object useable at run-time, while T is only be useable at compile time and could not be use through reflection.

Comment: I didn't really want to associate this question with Java, the type of generics I planned to implement were closer to .NET.  The language I am experimenting with is PHP which is interpreted.  So each object needs to carry the "variation" of a declared class with it.  Type erasure is impossible, because casting objects doesn't exist in PHP as it is dynamic.  However introspection is possible by either storing the variation (similar to your attribute example), or by flattening the classes, like in C++.  The question is, which is better?  I should have mentioned the language was dynamic.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a bit confusing,  your answer does address the two choices I have.  I'm just trying to consider the performance implications of creating each "concrete class" against the difficulty in maintaining the "attribute" across the language.

Comment: @Flosculus: I think that you should have tagged it PHP if it is the language your are experimenting with. Unfortunately, I really do not know enough with PHP. But with Python, which is also a dynamic language, I would try to use a custom annotation to pass the type information and maybe an abstract base class to store it.

Comment: It could be any language really, I'll try the first option, it looks like it will cascade nicely as each class reference will point to a specific class as opposed to a base class with a specific state (messy).

Answer (score 0):

Generics are just helpers at compile time. If we had no generics we would write code like this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new Date());
Date date = (Date) list.get(0);
```

Generics have been introduced to remove the necessary casts and we can now write:

```
ArrayList<Date> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Date());
Date date = list.get(0);
```

You might think that the `ArrayList` class manages an array of `Date`s internally, but in fact
it manages an array of `Object`s. The compiler inserts the missing casts at the places where you access an element.

Using generics has another benefit. The compiler can detect if you are making invalid casts. So it's not possible to write something like this:

```
ArrayList<Date> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Date());
String date = list.get(0);
```

You can verify that `ArrayList`s with different type parameters still compile to the same class using `new ArrayList<String>().getClass().equals(new ArrayList<Date>().getClass())`.

Take a look at the [Oracle Java Documentation about type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).